# Kinematics question related confusion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

[image: Solution of the question]A particle is thrown from ground such that at t = 2 sec its velocity is 20 ms^-1 & it makes an angle of 45° A particle is thrown from ground such that at t = 2 sec its velocity is 20 ms-1 & it makes an angle of 45° with horizontal.

- In this question i don't understand why acceleration due to gravity is being added at 4th step in solution. It should be subtracted as $V_y$ is in opposite direction.
- The solution could be wrong , just want to confirm i'm right or not.

Comment: [Homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093)
are considered off-topic here.

Comment: @josephh It's not obvious to me that it's homework or check-my-work.  It looks to me like someone found physics information somewhere else and wants to know why it is so.  It's not a well-worded question and the information that was found is pretty horrible, but it seems reasonable to ask why gt is added rather than subtracted.

Comment: $v_y=v_y-gt$ is nonsense.

Comment: It’s also the origin of the confusion.

Comment: @Ghoster  Yes.  Could have used U on the left instead of V, and again in the second-to-last line.  But even then, U is not a good variable to use because it might be confused with gravitational potential, which is how I would get to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final answer you have shown, 58.28 m, is correct and it is correct to add gravity at one point, but there are a number of typographical errors.

Here's how I would have done it:

Let $v_y(t)$ be the vertical component of velocity at time $t$ (in seconds) and $v_x(t)$ be the horizontal component.

$v_y(2) = 20\, \mathrm{m/s} \sin{(45)} = \frac{20}{\sqrt{2}}$ m/s  (the necessary information is given in the problem)

$v_y(t) = v_y(0) - gt $ (the standard kinetic equation for velocity with constant acceleration, assuming gravity acts in the negative $y$ direction).

At $t=2$ s:

$v_y(2) = v_y(0) - 2g $

And solving for $v_y(0)$:

$v_y(0) = v_y(2) + 2g $    (*notice the plus sign in here*)

Letting $g=10 \mathrm{m/s^2}$ and plugging in the known value for $v_y(2)$:

$v_y(0) = \left(\frac{20}{\sqrt{2}} + 20\right)$ m/s

If we assume that the gravitational energy is zero at the ground (we can choose where the zero is) then the total mechanical energy of the particle at $t=0$ s is:

$ME(0) = KE(0) + PE(0) = KE(0) + 0 = \frac{1}{2}m\left(v_x(0)^2+v_y(0)^2\right) = \frac{1}{2}mv(0)_x^2 +\frac{1}{2}m\left(\frac{20}{\sqrt{2}} + 20\right)^2\mathrm{m^2/s^2}$

where $KE$ is kinetic energy, $PE$ is gravitational potential energy, and $m$ is the (unknown) mass of the particle.

When the particle reaches its maximum height at some time $t=t^*$ the vertical component of its velocity, $v_y$ is zero, because it has stopped going up and is just about to come down.  Total mechanical energy is then:

$ME(t^*) = KE(t^*) + PE(t^*) = \frac{1}{2}m\left(v_x(t^*)^2+v_y(t^*)^2\right) + mgH(t^*) = \frac{1}{2}mv_x(t^*)^2 + 0 + 10 \mathrm{m/s^2} H(t^*) $

We now make two assumptions.  The first is that no forces act in the horizontal direction, in which case $v_x(0) = v_x(t^*)$.  The second is that mechanical energy is conserved, in which case $ME(0) = ME(t^*)$.  In that case:

$ \frac{1}{2}mv(0)_x^2 +\frac{1}{2}m\left(\frac{20}{\sqrt{2}} + 20\right)^2\mathrm{m^2/s^2} = \frac{1}{2}mv_x(t^*)^2 + 0 + 10 \mathrm{m/s^2} H(t^*)
 = \frac{1}{2}mv_x(0)^2 + 0 + 10 \mathrm{m/s^2} m H(t^*)$

Solving for $H(t^*)$ gives:

$H(t^*) = \frac{1}{20} \left(\frac{20}{\sqrt{2}} + 20\right)^2 \mathrm{m}
=  \frac{1}{20} \left(10\sqrt{2} + 20\right)^2 \mathrm{m} = 58.28 $ m

By the way, the question would have been clearer to me if stated like this:

A particle is thrown from the ground at $t=0$ s.  At $t=2$ s its velocity $v(t)$ is 20 m/s and it is traveling at an angle of 45° to the horizontal.  The height of the particle above the ground at time $t$ is $H(t)$.  You may assume that the only force acting on the particle after it is thrown is gravity and the acceleration due to gravity is 10 m/s$^2$. What is the maximum value of H(t)?

Comment: Thanks for the response; that was really helpful. However, I want to clarify that I didn't frame the question; it was already written that way, and I didn't make any changes. Thank you for your time, and could you please explain why my question was closed? I apologize if I asked something inappropriately; I'm new here.

Comment: @SiddharthKumarYadav  I guess that enough people decided it was a homework-like question, or a check-my-work question, and so closed it.  I didn't think it was but I don't have a lot of experience.  I wouldn't take it personally!